# Is it possible to strech/compress an interval of an axis in TChart?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10-seattle

I'd like to compress an interval of the left axis to underline graphically that values in that interval are less important then others. More precisely, if I have an Chart like [TChart unmodified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JAXw.png). Is is possible to compress the intervall 0-10 by an specific factor like it is done in [TChart modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4vAN.png)? Would it be possible by using two different (left) axis?

Comment: That interval is 1-10, not 0-10 (it's a log plot) and compressing it like you have shown doesn't make me feel that it's less important, it radically alters what the data appears to present - to the point of being confusing and bizarre.  A slope change on a log plot has a very, very important meaning.  Introducing a fake one artificially by deliberately distorting the scale seems very odd indeed.

Comment: Thanks J. It's definitly odd, I agree. However, it should make sense if you want to show a graph using logarithmic scale, but want to surpess small values (noise).

Comment: All I can say is that I've never seen data represented that way.  If you have a noise floor it's better to clamp or simply omit data below it.

Comment: J, all I can say is that I have an industry product here, that is exactly presenting the data that way. This is not my "invention". I've just to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a specific tool for that in [TeeChart Pro](https://www.steema.com/product/vcl) version. It's called [TAxisBreaksTool](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/tutorials/Library/TAxisBreaksTool.html). Multiple axes would be an alternative, which is also available in TeeChart Pro. You can obtain a fully functional [evaluation version](https://www.steema.com/downloads/vcl) and find an example at *All features\Welcome !\Tools\Axis Breaks* in the Features Demo project shipped with the binary installation or download the demo [here](https://www.steema.com/get_file/dc85e455496644c00663f6b081ce85db).

Comment: I've tried TAxisBreaksTool and I'm not sure if it is working on axis with a logarithmic scale appropriately. How this could be realized via multiple axes?

Comment: @DRASIT, you should use multiple custom axes as explained in [this tutorial](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/tutorials/UserGuide/Tutorials/tutorial4.htm#MultiAxis). However, as you can see in the example, you'll need a series associated to the custom axis for this to work. Therefore needing more than one series in the chart. Regarding axis breaks and log axes, I have added the issue to our bug list: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1490 to be fixed for future releases.